# Update thumbnail without asking for google login - Youtube API V3.0 - OAuth2.0 -

Tags: youtube-api, oauth-2.0

My goal is quite simple : Use php files that will log on my youtube account and upload custom thumbnails.

I already successfully used Youtube API V2 to upload videos with no problem,
but the V3 requires OAuth2.0, and I can't found a way to avoid my server keeps ask me "Please login from your google account"

I use the example from the official place, [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php?l=fr#uploading_a_custom_thumbnail_for_a_video) :

And created my OAuth token (tried web application and service) but it keeps ask me to log in...
I only want the php files to log on alone, because I want to share them to some friends that will be able to change thumbnails without having a google acount or knowing my youtube/google password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by getting a refresh token from [OAuth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and setting it in your youtube object.

[Here it explains a little more.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#standalone)

[And a step by step video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJjQPaPAfWM)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ibrahim, it solved my problem :) !
Except you didn't mentionned that I had to use $client->refreshToken('Refresh Token'); and then start the conditional : if ($client->getAccessToken()) { [...] . Very important to the others one who could encounter the problem : You need to use google developper console https://cloud.google.com/console and specify in APIs & Ath > Credentials the exact adress of your PHP script, and set a product name and email address in Consent Screen.